# Вывод кастомной информации в шаблоне TWIG в Drupal 8

Tags: php, drupal, twig

Как в TWIG шаблоне Drupal 8 выводить свою информацию? 
Допустим, пример: нужно вывести в страницу некоторую информацию, которую сгенерирует мой код. 
Вопрос такой: где конкретно в файле темы размещать сам код, кому надо сказать, чтобы шаблон обратился к этому коду с помощью некоторой переменной {{ myvar }}? 
Документации в интернете много, но там либо самые азы, либо сразу в самое пекло. 
Официальную документацию читаю, но пока трудно понять. 
Да, и есть ли где-то список системных переменных, в которых уже хранится информация? К примеру, чтобы мне не реализовывать функция, получающую имя сайта, я уверен, это уже сделано до меня.